# How to use gdal to generate overview tiles from existing zoom level 21 tiles?

Tags: gdal, tiles, gdal2tiles, xyz, xyz-tiles

I have multiple PNGs in a quadkey format for zoom level 21, for example:

> 023012311121232233120.PNG
> 023012311121232233121.PNG
> 023012311121232233122.PNG
> 023012311121232233123.PNG
> etc..

I used [mercantile](https://pypi.org/project/mercantile/) and copied/renamed them to /21/{x}/{y}.png format.
Serverd and tested them locally in a Mapbox GL JS app - works great.

Issue is I only have zoom level 21 now.

How can I use GDAL to generate the missing zoom levels 1-20?

I know **gdal2tiles.py** have a **--resume** flag, but what's the source/input for that script,  maybe **gdal2xyz.py** or **gdal_retile.py**?

Do I have another option to serve these tiles at a lower zoom levels, maybe without pre-generating them?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [tiletool](https://github.com/AMDmi3/tiletool) to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. tiletool doesn't help me because I'm using webp.

My solution is to disconnect the creation of the base_tiles in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo_utils/gdal2tiles.py.

Yes, this is a nasty hack, but instead of taking an hour, generating missing overview tiles now only takes seconds.

`## for tile_detail in tile_details:
      ## create_base_tile(conf, tile_detail)
      ## if not options.verbose and not options.quiet:
      ## base_progress_bar.log_progress()`

I would like to see another parameter --skip-overview-tiles in gdal2tiles :-)